# Creates object with hex param, using strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add a hex value into survey object and then save it into the database, but i can't do it, the name: it's kept well. But the suid: never reachs the database and does not appear as an unpermitted value in server log.

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController

def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @adjectives = Adjective.all
end

def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params, suid: Survey.new_suid)
    @survey.save  
end

private

    def survey_params
        params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :suid)
    end 
end
```

Here the model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :surveys
has_and_belongs_to_many :adjectives
belongs_to :nruser

def Survey.new_suid
    SecureRandom.hex(n=16)       
end 
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is:

```
def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
    @survey.suid = Survey.new_suid
    @survey.save  
end
```

Another way of doing it would be adding `suid` to `params` but I think this is easier. To add to `params`

```
params[:survey].merge(suid: Survey.new_suid)
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the answer, your way works great. But i'm looking the hard way hahah. How can i add suid to params?